# samba stuck at maximum of 1024 open files

Tags: samba, filesystems, network-share, ulimit

I'm running a Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) samba fileserver. I have a Windows 7 client which opens a large number of files while doing a copy of thousands of tiny files at once. It receives the error "Too many open files" at which point waiting a few seconds and clicking "Try again" resumes the download.

I've found a number of references that say to increase the number of open files available to Samba to solve the problem. I think that's a great idea, and am trying desperately to do so... but no matter what I do, it refuses to ever open more than 1024 files, and the copy issue will not go away!

Here is what I've tried:

I've set `ulimit -n 25000`.

I've also set /etc/security/limits.conf to:

```
* soft nofiles 25000
* hard nofiles 65000
root soft nofiles 25000
root hard nofiles 65000
```

I've ensured there is nothing in /etc/security/limits.d that overrides any of this.

I've checked that sysctl fs.file-max = 199468 which is more than adequate.

I cannot find any apparmor profiles that might be interfering with samba.

I have added a `limit nofile 25000 65000` stanza to /etc/init/smbd.conf

I've set max open files = 50000 in smb.conf and confirmed that it is taking effect via the samba log files:

```
[2011/10/28 01:30:16,  0] smbd/open.c:151(fd_open)
  Too many open files, unable to open more!  smbd's max open files = 50000
[2011/10/28 01:30:18,  0] lib/sysquotas.c:426(sys_get_quota)
  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
[2011/10/28 01:30:18,  0] lib/sysquotas.c:426(sys_get_quota)
  sys_path_to_bdev() failed for path [.]!
[2011/10/28 01:30:18,  0] smbd/open.c:151(fd_open)
  Too many open files, unable to open more!  smbd's max open files = 50000
[2011/10/28 01:30:19,  0] smbd/open.c:151(fd_open)
  Too many open files, unable to open more!  smbd's max open files = 50000
[2011/10/28 01:30:20,  0] smbd/open.c:151(fd_open)
  Too many open files, unable to open more!  smbd's max open files = 50000
```

I've confirmed that the issue happens when around 1000 files are open by using `lsof | wc -l` on the disk to give me an approximate count. No matter what I change, it's always 1000 where the "Try again" button appears and the copy gets interrupted. As soon as it drops back below 1000, you can click try again and it will resume copying.

Obviously this is a bug in Windows 7 or in Samba, I don't care which, all I care about is fixing it. Why won't my Samba open more than 1000-or-so files like I am asking it to do in so many ways? Is there some other limit I need to change?

Edit: symcbean had a good suggestion. Here are the results from inserting `ulimit -a > /tmp/samba-ulimits` into the pre-script section of /etc/init/smb.conf

```
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        10240
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              15969
nofiles              25000
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited
```

Also, I am running version 2:3.4.7~dfsg-1ubuntu3 of samba.

Comment: maybe add 'ulimit -a > /tmp/samba-ulimit' to the startup script to verify that it is being started with the limits you've configured?

Comment: Added the results of that to the question. It seems like the ulimit is being set properly?

Comment: A quick google suggests that Samab may implement the quota of the connected user - but I'd recommend reading further - one commentator suggests recompiling after './configure with --with-quotas=no' but see this also : http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbcquotas.1.html

Comment: I think I might have discovered a possible explanation, stemming from a separate problem. The ulimits I set in /etc/security/limits.conf are set properly for root, but I cannot get them to set for other users no matter what I do. If samba is using each user's limits, that might do it.  If I login as a non-root user, my ulimits are reset to 1024/1024 for open files. I've even tried having a specific line in limits.conf for each user, still nothing. It almost looks like this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=597225 except that is supposed to be fixed some time ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I have solved my issue, and in doing so come to a better understanding of how the ulimits work, at least in Ubuntu. There were a number of issues and I think I have sorted them all out.

First problem, and a silly one: `nofiles` should be `nofile` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Another more significant oversight: While I had ensured pam_limits.so was included in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, I didn't notice that there was also `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`. The latter file was the one that samba was using.

Fixing that issue appears to have fixed samba, which can now open as many file descriptors as it likes. Windows copies complete successfully. **Also note**: Samba does indeed use the appropriate user's ulimit, not the ulimits the smbd process started with, nor root's ulimit. `/etc/security/limits.conf` is the place to set this, once you have properly configured either (both?) `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` and `/etc/pam.d/samba` to use pam_limits.so

As for the other issue, where my user was stuck at 1024 hard/1024 soft limits, that was a combination of a few issues. First and foremost, despite having `/etc/pam.d/sshd` the ssh daemon does not use PAM unless you modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have "UsePAM yes". The default is "no", and without using PAM, pam_limits.so (which is responsible for applying limits.conf) does not even come into play.

Instead, the default ulimits for non-PAM logins seem to inherit from pid 1 (typically "init"). You can check those default pid 1 limits with `cat /proc/1/limits`. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, those limits are set as defaults in the kernel. There does not seem to be any way to modify them short of recompiling the kernel, or convincing the non-PAM application to use PAM.

I also just want to offer the advice that `cat /proc/<anypid>/limits` is a great way to debug the limits of any specific process you might be having trouble with. I wish I had discovered that sooner.

Comment: Thank you for both the question and the answer ) For those coming here through web search : something like `strace -e trace=%file -t -ff -o $logdir/smbd $smbpath/smbd -D` will show whether the present version of samba is using pam, and what files are opened; in my case it were `/etc/pam.d/common-account
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
/etc/pam.d/common-password
/etc/pam.d/common-session
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
/etc/pam.d/other
/etc/pam.d/samba`, but your mileage may vary

Answer (score 3):

I was working with ubuntu 14.04 lts and needed several hours to realize the following:

- samba-ad-dc is startet with upstart, so settings in /etc/security/limits.conf are irrelevant.
- limits are defined with the stanza in the file /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.conf
- there had to be a line inserted with the following code:

  limit nofile 16384 16384

After a restart all works fine, ps ax tells you the process id of samba and cat /proc/799/limits shows the correct Max open file limits of the process 799 (exchange 799 with your process id).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Samba init script has something like `ulimit -SHn 1024` in it? See `/etc/init.d/smb` or whatever your init script is.

Comment: Good thought, but that wasn't the issue. There's nothing in /etc/init/smbd.conf (upstart init script) or in /etc/default/samba that is setting any ulimits.